# How can i format time from 09:00:00.0000000 to 9:00 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following query :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 1 THEN 7
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 2 THEN 1 
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 3 THEN 2 
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 4 THEN 3 
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 5 THEN 4 
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 6 THEN 5 
WHEN rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek = 7 THEN 6
END AS StartDayOfTheWeek,
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, rpwh.StartDayOfTheWeek - 2) DayOfTheWeek,
rpwh.StartAt, rpwh.EndAt
FROM ResourceProfileWorkingHours rpwh
JOIN ResourceProfile rp ON rpwh.ResourceProfileId = rp.Id
WHERE rp.Alias = 'Accounts Payable'
ORDER BY StartDayOfTheWeek
```

Which returns:

```
StartDayOfTheWeek   DayOfTheWeek    StartAt              EndAt
1                   Monday          09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
2                   Tuesday         09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
3                   Wednesday       09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
4                   Thursday        09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
5                   Friday          09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
6                   Saturday        09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
7                   Sunday          09:00:00.0000000     17:00:00.0000000
```

What I need is for the StartAt time to be converted to 9:00 and the EndAt time to 17:00. I have tried writing the following line, but when I run it I get null values for both columns. How can i do this ?

```
FORMAT(rpwh.StartAt,'hh:mm') AS StartTime, FORMAT(rpwh.EndAt, 'hh:mm') AS EndTime
```

Comment: What are the datatypes?

Comment: *"How can i format time from 09:00:00.0000000 to 9:00 **in SQL Server**?"* Don't, format it in your presentation layer. If, however, you are only storing times accurate to 1 minute, then don't use a `time(7)`, use a `time(0)` (which is accurate to 1 second). If your times are only accurate to a minute, storing values accurate to 1/1000000 second is just a waste of storage space.

Comment: Date and time have no display format. Only their string representation does.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I think the DataTypes are [time](7)

Comment: @Larnu I am just looking to query an existing table which has the dataType [time](7). Is there not a way to convert this without changing this to [time](0) ?

Comment: @jamie123 The formatting should be done in the application, not the sQL.

Comment: Larnu is right that you should do this in the presentation layer, but if you can not do otherwise you can do the following: SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (5), <YourTimeCol>, 108)

Answer (score 0):

I used what @droebi suggested:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (5), <YourTimeCol>, 108)
```

This wasn't a perfect solution as it still has the start time as 09:00 instead of 9:00, but it is the closest I could get to what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
select format(cast(rpwh.StartAt as datetime2), 'hh:mm') as StartTime
    , format(cast(rpwh.EndAt as datetime2), 'hh:mm') as EndTime
```

I am formatting the time into a date and then only selecting the time.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't care about loosing the data type you can always go for a :

```
LEFT(CAST(StartAt, AS STRING), 5)
```

Comment: CAST doesn't use a comma, and STRING is not a sql server datatype.

Comment: Right, I'm used to BigQuery. I assumed that someone with a very limited experience would be able to translate it using the right syntaxe. I must have been wong :)